# Does php have a "if var is not empty, echo the var" function?

Tags: php

So I constantly write stuff like

```
if (!empty($someLongVar['nestedArrayKey'])) echo $someLongVar['nestedArrayKey'];
```

or

```
<?= !empty($someLongVar['nestedArrayKey']) ? $someLongVar['nestedArrayKey'] : "" ?>
```

I feel this is a waste of valuable programmer time. So is there some kind of shorthand for this that I'm missing? A function like

```
echoIf($someLongVar['nestedArrayKey'])
```

would save a lot of space and typing for thousands of programmers out there.

It seems impossible to write such a function myself because PHP throws a warning everytime i reference a nonexistant variable.

Comment: You can write it for yourself?

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to do it without invoking a function checking first is to just hide the warning using `echo @$someLongVar['nestedArrayKey'];` which echos if it exists and not if it's unset. I'd _really_ recommend against just hiding warnings though, it tends to bite you later.

Comment: Yeah it's not very clean, but if you do it like Austin presented in his answer, it can't cause any damage. Wrapping it in a function that explicitly handles if the var is better. Echoing a potentially undefined var is kind undefined behaviour:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can suppress the warnings with the `@` operator.

```
function echoIf($variable) {
    if(!empty($variable))
        echo $variable;
}

echoIf(@$myVariable['test']);
```

Comment: This is perfect, I had missed the @ operator. Thanks!

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst Downvote wasn't me but the error suppression operator is considered bad practise. It's like coding with a blindfold.

Comment: Its even worse practice to fill your code with `if(!empty($array['key'])) echo ($array['key']);`. Php programmers seem very touchy about this for some reason! Many other languages lets you work with undefined variables much more freely.

Comment: By the way I found out that if you make your function as a pass by reference it wont raise an error. So no need for @ if you declare function as `function echoIf(&$variable)`. My code is cleaner.. and I'm happy!

Comment: @JoakimBlomberg references are even worse. There is almost no need for them in PHP and abusing them to suppress an error is, well, abusing them. Why don't you just make sure the array key is there in the first place?

Comment: @Gordon I'm trying to explain that I think it gets very verbose to do that check every time, writing variable names twice in a row. In many other languages its completely normal to pass an undefined variable to another function, and letting that function take responsibility to check if it is undefined. The echoIf function checks if the variable is undefined - whats the harm?

Comment: @JoakimBlomberg it's unneeded when you instead make sure that they key exists in the first place. As an alternative, consider making the multidim array an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ifVar($var) {
   if(isset($var)) if(!empty($var)) echo $var."\n";
}
```

Comment: This would raise a NOTICE warning if $var is undefined